# A 90s show using handheld Internet

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a 90s TV show. I want to say it was by Gene Roddenberry and it wasn’t *Earth: Final Conflict*, but it was around the same time.

In it they used this handheld VR looking kind of Internet surfing, where they would use their hands like they were surfing with their hand outside a car to surf the web.

Comment: There was also the scene from Johnny Mnemonic (1995) when Keanu Reeves builds and uses a virtual keyboard/screen to get on the internet and do some hacking. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzRjtvMQds4&t=78s

Answer (score 24):

A few years before *Earth: Final Conflict* there was a TV series *Tekwar*, based on the William Shatner novels (at least in name); some scenes in episodes involved 'hackers' making odd, surf-like gestures while doing what was supposed to look like  cyberpunk hacking (unfortunately, like a lot of Canadian made shows it was fairly low budget.)

Comment: Bah, you got me by three minutes while I scrounged up a screenshot.

Comment: @Xantec Well you both get an upvote; I spent 2 minutes looking for a good screenshot, and gave up because I didn't really want to rewatch it. :)

Answer (score 24):

You might be thinking of [TekWar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TekWar), based on the novels by William Shatner. There were four TV movies followed by a single ten-episode season. In the show they could navigate and interact with the "matrix" in VR with hand movements.

[image: cruising the matrix]